# Как сделать необязательное заполнение полей QLineEdit для дальнейших расчетов?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при заполнении не всех полей в форме у меня крашится калькулятор с таким ответом:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

---

Вот форма, в которой есть 3 поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она суммирует все три поля и выводит ответ.
Но если я введу значения только в первое и второе, то она крашится.

Как сделать поле необязательным для заполнения?

**main.py:**

```
import sys
from calc import *

class MyWin (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Button.clicked.connect(self.getSum)

def getSum(self):
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None

    a = int(self.ui.a.text())
    b = int(self.ui.b.text())
    c = int(self.ui.c.text())
    s = a+b+c

    self.ui.sum.setText(str(s))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**calc.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(195, 172)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(195, 172))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(195, 172))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 171, 141))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.a.setObjectName("a")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.a)
        self.b = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.b.setObjectName("b")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.b)
        self.c = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.c.setObjectName("c")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.c)
        self.Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.Button.setObjectName("Button")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Button)
        self.sum = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.sum.setObjectName("sum")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.sum)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.sum.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
```

Comment: А вы сами подумайте, что происходит когда вы преобразовываете в int или складываете "None". Ну и сделаете проверку на то, что `text() != None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...


    def getSum(self):
        a = self.ui.a.text()
        b = self.ui.b.text()
        c = self.ui.c.text()

        a = int(a) if a else 0
        b = int(b) if b else 0
        c = int(c) if c else 0
        s = a + b + c

#        self.ui.sum.setText(str(s))
        self.ui.sum.setNum(s)

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!